# python and angularjs file download

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, download, filesize

When a user clicks on download button on the UI, I want to download a file that is residing on a share. It works good with <1gb data.  but large files, it fails.  It doesn't give any error, but i can see that the spinner to download on the bottom left hand corner of chrome stops after 1gb.
Here is my python code

```
filename = os.path.basename(pathToFile)
        chunk_size = 8192
        content_type = mime.from_file(pathToFile)
        response = StreamingHttpResponse(FileWrapper(open(pathToFile), chunk_size),
                                         content_type=content_type)
        response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(pathToFile)
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % filename
```

Here is javascript code

```
 $scope.downloadFile = function(path) {
      return "/download_file?file=" + encodeURIComponent("somePath");
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does the problem occur on other browsers as well?

Comment: Try downloading the file using `curl`, `wget` or similar command line tool. You might then be able to see what the problem is, e.g. your file system might have a 1GB max file size.

Comment: Yes, on other browsers also same issue.  We are using uwsgi and nginx.  I am thinking there me a default configuration which allows only 1GB.  I tried to add nginx conf with proxy_max_temp_file_size 5120m; Didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding the below parameters to my nginx.conf file.

```
location /<Your download api path> {           
        uwsgi_pass django;
        uwsgi_read_timeout 300s;

        uwsgi_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Connection '';
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        chunked_transfer_encoding on;
        proxy_cache off;

    }
```